# How to create Middleware for sockets?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Using node + express we can attach Middlewares to routes. But this can be done when using sockets?

**socket.on('foo',middleware?)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to execute a function on every socket message, use this:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.use((packet, next) => {
    if (packet.doge === true) return next();
    next(new Error('Not a doge error'));
  });
});
```

For middleware that will run only on the initial socket connection, use this:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
  if (socket.request.headers.cookie) return next();
  next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```

Take a look at the docs, it's pretty good:
https://socket.io/docs/server-api/